# ORACLE GROUP BY error

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL query is the following:

```
SELECT 
  oh.ORDER_NUMBER, oh.CREATED_TS, stat.STATE, stat.TIMESTAMP 
FROM 
 IMPL_OH_ORDER_HEADER oh,
 SNCR_ORDER_DISPOSITION stat,
 SNCR_ORDER_DISP_HEAD stathead,
 IMPL_CUST_ACCOUNT cust 
WHERE 
 stat.DISP_TRANSACTION_ID=stathead.DISP_TRANSACTION_ID
 and stathead.TRANSACTION_ID=oh.TRANSACTION_ID 
 and oh.ACCOUNT_ID=cust.ACCOUNT_ID 
 and stat.CATEGORY=100 
 and oh.USER_ID='a' 
 and cust.ACCOUNT_NUM='123'
 GROUP BY oh.ORDER_NUMBER
 ORDER BY stat.TRX_SEQ DESC;
```

It is giving the following error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

If I remove the GROUP BY expression, I don't get the error.

What is correct GROUP BY syntax?

Research: A google search says that, if AGGREGATE functions are used, I should have all fields not used by aggregate function in the GROUP BY clause. So I tried to modify the GROUP BY expression to `GROUP BY oh.ORDER_NUMBER, oh.CREATED_TS, stat.TIMESTAMP, stat.STATE`.

Yet I am getting the same error.

Please help.

Comment: when there is no need to groupby why you are doing so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you have `STAT.TRX_SEQ` in the *order by* list.

If you use the *group by* clause together with the *order by* clause, you must either order by a column on which you grouped or on an aggregated value.

This rule also applies to the *selected* values: they're either part of the group by or aggregate functions (or pseudo columns).

Comment: Changed to the following : `GROUP BY oh.ORDER_NUMBER ORDER BY 1 DESC;` yet am getting the same error

Comment: Thanks. The following query worked `GROUP BY oh.ORDER_NUMBER, oh.CREATED_TS, stat.TIMESTAMP, stat.STATE
 ORDER BY 1,4 DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one and see??

```
SELECT   OH.ORDER_NUMBER,
         OH.CREATED_TS,
         STAT.STATE,
         STAT.TIMESTAMP
FROM     IMPL_OH_ORDER_HEADER OH,
         SNCR_ORDER_DISPOSITION STAT,
         SNCR_ORDER_DISP_HEAD STATHEAD,
         IMPL_CUST_ACCOUNT CUST
WHERE    STAT.DISP_TRANSACTION_ID = STATHEAD.DISP_TRANSACTION_ID
AND      STATHEAD.TRANSACTION_ID = OH.TRANSACTION_ID
AND      OH.ACCOUNT_ID = CUST.ACCOUNT_ID
AND      STAT.CATEGORY = 100
AND      OH.USER_ID = 'A'
AND      CUST.ACCOUNT_NUM = '123'
GROUP BY OH.ORDER_NUMBER,
         OH.CREATED_TS,
         STAT.STATE,
         STAT.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY STAT.TRX_SEQ DESC;
```